# DependencyProperty on ViewModel of UserControl not updated by Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a UserControl which is used as the basis for items in an ItemsControl:

Main Page xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Systems, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ServerGroupControl>
                <local:ServerGroupControl.DataContext>
                    <local:ServerGroupControlViewModel System="{Binding}"/>
                </local:ServerGroupControl.DataContext>
            </local:ServerGroupControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am trying to set the 'System' property of each ViewModel (such that it can handle the data for the view), but the property is never set!

Here is the dependancy property declaration in the view model class:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SystemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "System",
        typeof(ServerGroup),
        typeof(ServerGroupControlViewModel)
    );

    public ServerGroup System
    {
        get { return (ServerGroup)GetValue(SystemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SystemProperty, value); }
    }
```

The property always keeps it's default value. Any ideas on why this setup does not work?

Comment: What mad-man has DPs in a VM?

Comment: Also, how exactly did you determine that the property is never set? If you set a breakpoint in that setter you will always be disappointed as the binding system does not use them.

Comment: @H.B I'm inspecting the view later (breaking in the handler of a command which uses the property). I have indeed read about how the setter is skipped as per wpf's magic.

Comment: Alright, another unknown: Does the binding *actually work* without throwing [binding errrors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)? That is what i suspect here.

Comment: Yes, no binding errors thrown unless I try Mode=TwoWay (as was suggested by a previous answer that disappeared). The error from Mode=TwoWay specifies that 'Path or XPath' must be set, i.e. can't two way bind to the DataContext of the DataTemplate which makes sense.

Comment: Those are **not** *binding errors*. Did you read the link i posted?

Comment: @H.B. Did not even know they existed! This is gold. Found an error:

Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ServerGroupControlViewModel' (HashCode=58112803); target property is 'System' (type 'ServerGroup')

Comment: That is exactly what i suspected, no DataContext, no name scope, nothing. You are kind of screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comment i would suspect that the binding does not work because there is no `DataContext` in the place where you try to bind.

Your VM is not a `FrameworkElement` so it has no `DataContext` property, presumably it is not `Freezable` either (and hence might lack an inheritance context too) so i suspect that this won't work. (`ElementName` and `RelativeSource` won't work either then, by the way)

I suggest you approach this differently, also i do not recommend the use of DPs in VMs due to thread-affinity and other problems.

---

Here's one gem of a work-around:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <local:ServerGroupControl Name="sgc">
        <local:ServerGroupControl.Resources>
            <local:ServerGroupControlViewModel x:Key="context"
                System="{Binding Parent.DataContext, Source={x:Reference sgc}}" />
        </local:ServerGroupControl.Resources>
        <local:ServerGroupControl.DataContext>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="context" />
        </local:ServerGroupControl.DataContext>
    </local:ServerGroupControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Yeah, please don't do that...

Comment: Giving up on current approach - seemingly impossible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Andy: You're welcome, been constructing a horrifying workaround for fun if you are interested.

Comment: @Andy: Really? Well, i obviously could not test this with your specific control, so it might not work in every context...

Answer (score 0):

When a property is set through databinding, the explicit setter function is not called.

If you really want to intercept the setting action, you can do this via a callback that you set when initializing the Dependency Property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SystemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "System",
        typeof(ServerGroup),
        typeof(ServerGroupControlViewModel),
        new PropertyMetadata
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = SystemPropertyChanged
        }
    );


static void SystemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ServerGroupControlViewModel receiver = (ServerGroupControlViewModel)d;
    ServerGroup newValue = e.NewValue as ServerGroup;

    // Add any appropriate handling logic here.
}
```

Comment: I have previously attempted to add the PropertyChangedCallback to the property metadata and wait for it to be called. It is never called (breakpoint never hit)!

Comment: @Andy - in your previous attempt, was the value applied explicitly or via binding? If you set the value explicitly then (I'm 90% sure that) it will use your property setter function, but if you use binding than that callback will fire.

Comment: Via the binding (as per the supplied snippet). Have not tried setting it explicitly yet.